# trajectory_from_mdtraj requires simtk.unit, which is not installed

Tags: python, openpathsampling

I am trying to load my MD trajectory to postprocess the velocities. Although I use the same exact script on the [OPS website](http://openpathsampling.org/latest/index.html), I get the following error:

```
trajectory_from_mdtraj requires simtk.unit, which is not installed
```

I tried to pip install simtk which didn't solve the issue. Any suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Did you tried with *pip install simtk.unit*?

Comment: Could you provide a link to the script you are using? The link in the post points to the main website. Also, do you have mdtraj installed? And I don't believe simtk can be installed with pip, because it needs another library in C++.

Answer (score 3):

The error message here is out of date -- `simtk.unit` was renamed to `openmm.unit` by the OpenMM maintainers. So this really means that you don't have OpenMM installed on your system. (Error message will be fixed in [this pull request](https://github.com/openpathsampling/openpathsampling/pull/1122)).

If you're not planning to use OpenMM for dynamics, then you probably want to load a trajectory using something like the solution in [this answer](https://mattermodeling.stackexchange.com/a/6974/2004).

If you *are* planning to use OpenMM for dynamics (as the examples do), then you'll definitely want to install OpenMM! You can do that with `conda install -c conda-forge openmm`. Note that OpenMM can not (yet) be installed with `pip`. You can see other optional installations that are supported by OPS in the docs on [integration with other packages](http://openpathsampling.org/latest/install.html#integration-with-other-packages).